# Cannot sucessfully process and display api response in alert box

Tags: javascript, html

I am using Console World News API, which is great. Works well, easy to get the api access token. My problem now is when I try to fetch that data and display it in an alert box, it just doesn't cooperate and gives me an error message saying unexpected token "<" in the console.

```
function getNews() {
  const userinput = document.getElementById('topic').value;
  console.log('Getting latest news...');
  fetch(`https://api.worldnewsapi.com/api/v1/news?apikey=MYAPIKEYPURPOSELYBLOCKEDOUT&q=${userinput}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      const firstNews = data.articles[0];
      console.log(firstNews);
      const title = firstNews.title;
      console.log(title);
      const description = firstNews.description;
      console.log(description);
      const url = firstNews.url;
      console.log(url);
      alert(title + "\n\n" + description + "\n\n" + url);
      sessionStorage.setItem('news', JSON.stringify(firstNews)); // save the first news article in session storage
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
}

function openArticle() {
  const news = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('news'));
  if (news && confirm("Do you want to open your news in a new window?")) {
    window.open(news.url, '_blank');
  } else {
    // User clicked "Cancel"
  }
}
```

I tried different methods of alerting and saving but it just didn't work.

Comment: add the sample api response that you get from the fetch action.